# How to get specified format youtube video download link using youtube-dl in python

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-dl

currently i am doing this

```
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL
y=YoutubeDL()
url = 'youtube url'
r=y.extract_info(url, download=False)

r.get('formats') contain all video, audio link
```

I need only specified format video audio link.

But i dont know where to specify or which param to set for format

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`format` parameter](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/b3613d36da14ab527166326707c0f911d192144d/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L139), which accepts the same value as the `--format` option:

```py
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL
y = YoutubeDL({
    'format': 'bestaudio',
})
url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKcj'
r = y.extract_info(url, download=False)
print(r['ext'])
print(r['url'])
```

Prints:

```
m4a
https://r3---sn-h5q7dned.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?<...>
```